# Continuous independent variable using Lm function in R

Tags: r

I ran a regression in data set cwm. Intention:

- Test the correlation between cm14 (continuous) and medran (continuous)
- Control for type, disint, leverage, and end, which affect cm14

  `ranking <- lm(cm14 ~ medran + cm10a + type + disint + leverage + end, data=cwm)
  summary(ranking)`

The summary results gave an independent regression figure for every category in medran.

How can I obtain a figure for the overall impact of medran on cm14?

Comment: If `medran` is continuous there are no "categor[ies] in medran".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of your variables is categorical, you can use `anova(ranking)` to do this.